# return an array in c# with Join

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a function to get the data from the database and return it as a string array.
I have tried the below code but near the `string.Join(",", x.ToArray());` it gives me an error saying it cannot be converted to [].

What want to do is I want to return all the JobID's that are executed from the query in an array with comma separated as a string array or a int array.

please help me to figure this out

```
public string[] GetAgentJobId()
            {
                string x;
                string[] y = new string[100];
                var agentName = _context.Table1.SqlQuery
                     ("Select * from Table1 " +
                     "CROSS APPLY string_split(AssignTo, ',') where value = 'name'").ToArray();
    
                foreach (var m in agentName)
                {
                    x = m.JobID.ToString();
                    y = string.Join(",", x.ToArray());
                }
                return y;
            }
```

Any help is appreciated Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide input and expected output? Do you want to return all JobID's as a string? with comma separation?

Comment: You're assigning a string to a variable declared as an array, that will not work.

Comment: You can;t not return an array with Join. Join convert IEnumerable to string with delimiter >

Comment: Are you maybe trying to have "y" be a `List<string>` where you can `.Add()` each JobID?

Comment: An `x.ToArray()` (with x a string) will return an array of all separate characters in "x" - is that *really* what you want?

Answer (score 1):

`string.Join()` not return the array you can try like this

```
public string[] GetAgentJobId()
{
            
     var agentName = _context.Table1.SqlQuery
     ("Select * from Table1 " +
     "CROSS APPLY string_split(AssignTo, ',') where value = 
     name'").ToArray();
     string[] y = new string[agentName.Length];
     int i = 0;
     foreach (var m in agentName)
     {
           y[i] = m.JobID.ToString();
           i++;

     }
     return y;
}
```